# IBM WebSphere MQ vms client

Tags: ibm-mq

I am very new to IBM WebSphere MQ.

in our environment we have a VMS server that using the mq service via client .
the mq server is a part of cluster,the issue is that the client communicate with one server only .

i'm looking for solution the survivability so the client can communicate with cluster (queue name , client needs queue name and server name).

Appreciate for your help

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you look into using a Client channel definition table (CCDT) file. You can populate your CCDT file with `CLNTCONN` definitions one for each queue manager in the cluster that you want your client connection to choose from. When defining the `CLNTCONN` channels however, give them all the same value for the `QMNAME` field (i.e. not the real queue manager name). The cluster name might be an appropriate string to use but is certainly not essential.

Then in the client application, have the application use that string instead of the queue manager name that it is currently using, along with an asterisk which notes that the application is aware that the string it is using is not the real queue manager name.

Will look like this:-

```
QMName = "*MY.CLUSTER.NAME";
MQCONN(&QMName,
       &hConn,
       &CompCode,
       &Reason);
```

**Further reading**

- [Client channel definition table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016730_.htm)
- [Examples of MQCONN calls](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q027540_.htm)
- [Example 1. Queue manager name includes an asterisk (*)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q027560_.htm)